# How will less flour affect molten lava cakes?

Tags: cake, chocolate, flour

I made some molten cakes the other day, using this [recipe from Betty Crocker](http://www.bettycrocker.com/recipes/molten-chocolate-cakes/be3b3ba1-f88e-4da1-9c89-75f4f1a08bba). However, it is very "cakey." The molten cakes I've had before in restaurants have had more of a "truffle" consistency. Much denser, and smoother in consistency (I'm unsure if this is what is meant by "fudge like" or not). The molten part of the restaurant cake also seems thicker. I'm assuming this is related to the relative densities of the cakes.

Is this a simple instance of just needing to reduce the flour? Or is there more to it?

Here is a list of the ingredients the recipe calls for:

> - Unsweetened baking cocoa
> - 6 oz semisweet baking chocolate, chopped
> - 1/2 cup plus 2 tablespoons butter or margarine
> - 3 whole eggs
> - 3
>     egg yolks
> - 1 1/2
>     cups powdered sugar
> - 1/2 cup Gold Medal® all-purpose flour*
>     Additional powdered sugar, if desired
>     Sugared kumquats, if desired

Here is a picture of the desired molten cake: [image: desired molten cake]

versus the Betty Crocker one:

[image]

Comment: It's more likely an overcooking issue. A) whet time and temperature does the recipe call for and B) how accurate is your oven dial?

Comment: 450 F for 12-14 minutes. Unsure of how accurate my oven is. however, the result did look like their example of a correct cake, which is why I wondered if it was the recipe.

Comment: It may have looked correct externally, but if it was more cakey inside it could be overcooked and thus dried out.

Comment: why am I so hungry now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the molten lava cake you have pictured from any restaurant isn't made up of cake. It's really a BROWNIE! That is why the different density and the difference in richness. I know. I make them in a high end restaurant in Wisconsin.

Comment: This is very useful information. To make it *fit* better on the site, it could be improved by changing the wording a bit to directly answer the question. Edits like that are best when done by the original poster. Welcome to Seasoned Advice! I hope you stick around.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not getting the exact results you want, I suggest you experiment with a few things and expect a few learning experiences along the way. Look at three or four other recipes and look for ideas of things to try.

As noted in the comments you might want to adjust cooking time and/or temperature. If you're oven is too cool you might have cooked the inside more to get the same external look than if it had been at full temperature. So try more heat or less time. If you think it was too soft inside do the reverse.

That said, it sounds like you don't really like the intended results from the recipe, so you'll probably want to make other variations.

Depending on how things are combined in the preparation process you can try experiment with flour and fat levels. Remember that if you liked the outer layers adjusting the flour will effect those too. Some recipes include unmelted chocolate pieces put into the cake as you pour it into the dish. That will give you more of the texture you see in the first picture (the heavier chocolate will depress into the weak structures below it). You might also want to try adjusting the overall chocolate amount and how much butter you melt into it.

Answer (score 2):

several key elements:

- the shape of the mold changes the surface area, more area = more cooked cake.
- those two chocolates were different.

  - sugar will make the chocolate more sticky (changes viscosity)
  - fat will make the chocolate more rich (and hold better)

some tips:

- you can freeze the chocolate "truffle" part so that it doesn't bake as fast.
- you can also try to substitute with an actual truffle.
- you can make the center part bigger, by changing proportions, this is very similar to your idea of reducing the flour.

Comment: There is no separate "truffle part" in that recipe.  Like most molten cake recipes, it is a single homogeneous batter.

Comment: I see, my friend uses frozen chocolate square in the middle.